# Creating SO via Webservice says customerID does not exist

Tags: web-services, acumatica

Hello I have created a routine to connect two Systems: XXXXWIN10 that is a local system with  Acumatica. XXXWIN10 system have to send information about sales order to Acumatica. I'm using screen webservice in order to create a Sales Order. When I execute to test my code, each time I receive that customerID could not be empty but I'm sending all the information and also the customer exist. Do you see something wrong in my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Conexionspa.apitest;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Conexionspa
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string CVECLI = "";
            string CVEORDEN = "";
            string FEC_ORDEN = "";
            string DESCUENTO = "";
            string CVESERVI = "";
            string CANTIDAD = "";
            decimal QTY = 0;
            string PIEZAS = "";
            string CAPA_REQ = "";
            string CAPA_OBT = "";
            string KILOS = "";
            string TIPO_ACERO = "";
            string RECIPIENTE = "";
            string DUREZA_OBT = "";
            string FEC_PROMES = "";
            string PRECIOME = "";
            decimal PRECIO = 0;
            string IMPORTE = "";
            string PORPIEZA = "";
            string MONEDA = "";
            string TIPOCAMBIO = "";
            string PLANTA = "";
            string conexion = @"Data Source = XXXXWIN10,2433; Initial Catalog = SYSXXXX; User ID = sa; Password = XXXYYYZZZ";
            string queryString = "SELECT CVECLI, CVEORDEN, FEC_ORDEN, DESCUENTO, CVESERVI, CANTIDAD, PIEZAS, CAPA_REQ, CAPA_OBT, KILOS, TIPO_ACERO, RECIPIENTE, DUREZA_OBT, FEC_PROMES, PRECIOME, IMPORTE, PORPIEZA, MONEDA, TIPOCAMBIO, PLANTA FROM [Ordenes de Trabajo] WHERE STATUS = 2";
            SqlConnection conection = new SqlConnection(conexion);
            try
            {
                conection.Open();
                SqlDataReader leeordenes = null;
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conection);
                leeordenes = Command.ExecuteReader();
                while (leeordenes.Read())
                {
                    CVECLI = leeordenes["CVECLI"].ToString();
                    CVEORDEN = leeordenes["CVEORDEN"].ToString();
                    FEC_ORDEN = leeordenes["FEC_ORDEN"].ToString();
                    DateTime FECORDEN = DateTime.Parse(FEC_ORDEN);
                    DESCUENTO = leeordenes["DESCUENTO"].ToString();
                    CVESERVI = leeordenes["CVESERVI"].ToString();
                    CANTIDAD = leeordenes["CANTIDAD"].ToString();
                    decimal.TryParse(CANTIDAD, out QTY);
                    PIEZAS = leeordenes["PIEZAS"].ToString();
                    CAPA_REQ = leeordenes["CAPA_REQ"].ToString();
                    CAPA_OBT = leeordenes["CAPA_OBT"].ToString();
                    KILOS = leeordenes["KILOS"].ToString();
                    TIPO_ACERO = leeordenes["TIPO_ACERO"].ToString();
                    RECIPIENTE = leeordenes["RECIPIENTE"].ToString();
                    DUREZA_OBT = leeordenes["DUREZA_OBT"].ToString();
                    FEC_PROMES = leeordenes["FEC_PROMES"].ToString();
                    DateTime FECPROMES = DateTime.Parse(FEC_PROMES);
                    PRECIOME = leeordenes["PRECIOME"].ToString();
                    decimal.TryParse(PRECIOME, out PRECIO);
                    IMPORTE = leeordenes["IMPORTE"].ToString();
                    PORPIEZA = leeordenes["PORPIEZA"].ToString();
                    MONEDA = leeordenes["MONEDA"].ToString();
                    TIPOCAMBIO = leeordenes["TIPOCAMBIO"].ToString();
                    PLANTA = leeordenes["PLANTA"].ToString();

                    apitest.Screen context = new apitest.Screen();
                    context.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                    context.EnableDecompression = true;
                    context.Timeout = 1000000;
                    context.Url = "http://localhost/XXXYYY/Soap/APITEST.asmx";
                    try
                    {
                        LoginResult result = context.Login("Admin@XXXYYY:P000", "AdminXXX");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ep)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error en las credenciales" + ep.Message );
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
                        context.SO301000Clear();

                        SO301000Content[] SO301000result = context.SO301000Submit
                            (
                                new Command[]
                                {
                                   new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },
                                   new Value { Value = "TADEO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer  },
                                   new Value { Value = "0000007", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },
                                   new Value { Value = CVEORDEN, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.ExternalReference },
                                   new Value { Value = FEC_ORDEN, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Date },
                                   new Value { Value = CVESERVI, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID },
                                   new Value { Value = CANTIDAD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity },
                                   new Value { Value = PIEZAS, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Description },
                                   new Value { Value = CAPA_REQ + " " + CAPA_OBT + " " + KILOS + " " + TIPO_ACERO + " " + RECIPIENTE + " " + DUREZA_OBT, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.LineDescription },
                                   new Value { Value = FEC_ORDEN, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.RequestedOn },
                                   new Value { Value = PRECIOME, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice, Commit = true },
                                   new Value { Value = "NA", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UOM },
                                   new Value { Value = "USD", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Currency },
                                   new Value { Value = "AP3", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse },

                                    SO301000.Actions.Save,
                                }
                            );
                        Console.WriteLine("Orden registrada");
                        Thread.Sleep(9000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error al insertar O.T en Acumatica: " + ex.Message);
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception mensaje)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error en las credenciales del SPA ó Acumatica Web Service: " + mensaje);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add Commit = true after your customerid. new Value { Value = "TADEO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer, Commit = true  },

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you should first set Order Type and Order Number, and only then all the other fields, i.e.

```
new Command[]
{
    new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },
    new Value { Value = "0000007", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },
    new Value { Value = "TADEO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer  },
    //rest of fields
    SO301000.Actions.Save,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, order it is important and I could solve it